# Meteor subscription data not showing up in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor

I'm using [Differential's meteor-boilerplate](https://github.com/Differential/meteor-boilerplate) as a starting point for a simple app. Currently it includes iron-router 1.0.6.

**I'd like to handle routes such as /epidodes/5 where it displays document data from an Episode collection based on an episodeNumber property.**

Here's a sample document, which I can query using "meteor shell":

```
> Episodes.findOne({episodeNumber: 5})
{ title: 'Ingaus carsur diain nofaex deradisancom.',
description: 'Warde tu alde ationsome an. Ryretyening lowtheland iti combeex. Proset    mafacic lyed oan odiscon alsub isper. Es tiestionthe perconsiy lytion ac tioners inter mycal. Eded uernlarer indis u minca taladpaicar mycom. Cuopbleerpo tem ausin fored alersed mentfa eredal iterning peunbae ex. Oer omade the ican alfor pening. Thederder ingpro reumer esconex. Postions ery terre tionthepen aatcoming tyre beter protioni tionedpe riter. Toreraners typle erntyraa solyi. Themag alrei raat protionaset edcom cypro atapasi afthe iun edterfiassup.',
vimeoId: '80816872',
publishedOn: 510603296882,
free: false,
rating: 2,
episodeNumber: 5,
_id: 'Ewznhyex5puyccSFK' }
```

**However, it is not showing up in Google Chrome's console.**

Here are the relevant files:

**collections/episodes.js**

```
Episodes = new Mongo.Collection('episodes');
```

**routes.js**

```
Router.map(function() {                                                                                              

// some other routes...

// the route where I'm stuck
this.route('episodesShow', {
  path: '/episodes/:episodeNumber',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('episode', this.params.episodeNumber);
  },
  data: function() {
    return Episodes.findOne({episodeNumber: this.params.episodeNumber});
  }
});
```

**server/publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish("episode", function(episodeNumber) {
  check(episodeNumber, String);
  return Episodes.findOne({episodeNumber: episodeNumber});
});
```

Any guidance on how to troubleshoot this to see why data isn't showing up on the client side would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a problem but in data you can simply return Episodes.findOne() since you published only one

Comment: I tried Episodes.findOne() and it didn't work, either.  I've also tried looking at the WebSockets trace from the Network panel in Chrome's console and it shows the "sub" statement as well as a corresponding "ready" statement, so it looks like it's wired up, but still only an empty array is returned.  Is there a better way to troubleshoot the connection between the client and server?

Comment: Does Episodes.find().fetch() return soemthing in console?

Comment: @Sindis it returns an empty array.  I've also tried adding onReady and onError to my subscribe call and it executes the onReady callback.

Comment: Try console log in your publish function to see if it returns correct value

Comment: It returns https://gist.github.com/chip/4810183c2feaad41baec, which isn't what I'm expecting.

Comment: This is cursor, paste here what .fetch() returns(you should return cursor ofc., but it is easier to see what you return when you fetch it)

Comment: Both the console and the server side return an empty array.  When I run the query using "meteor shell", it returns the data I expect.

Comment: Make sure this collection is seen for both client and server and check if ids are corect, one of those two have to be incorrect. If you still think something is wrong push it to some repostiory and I'll have closer look

Comment: Thanks Sindis, but I had another issue. I'll post an answer separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was that I had another subscription named **episodes** which is the same as the collection name.

**collections/episodes.js**

```
Episodes = new Mongo.Collection('episodes');
```

**server/publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish("episodes", function() {
  return Episodes.find({});
});
```

I changed the name of the published record set to **episodesList**:

```
Meteor.publish("episodesList", function() {
  return Episodes.find({});
});
```

What I also did to solve the issue was create a file called **client/main.js** and subscribed to the **episodesList** that I'd already published:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe("episodesList");
});
```

I was never able to get the **episodeNumber** parameter to work in the **/episodes/:episodeNumber** route.  I was able to get **_id** to work, but that was ugly, so I created a **slug** attribute and that worked fine.

Here's the update definition in **routes.js**:

```
  this.route('singleEpisode', {
    path: '/episodes/:slug',
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('episodesList');
    },
    data: function() {
      return Episodes.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
    }
  });
```

Comment: You published whole collection so you don't need another one with 'slug', you already have it available on client

Comment: Ah, I understand better now.  I guess that record set publication was interfering with the other one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to return cursor and not array, like:

```
Meteor.publish("episode", function(episodeNumber) {
  check(episodeNumber, String);
  return Episodes.find({episodeNumber: episodeNumber});
});
```

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work.  I also tried changing the "data" function of the route to use "find" instead of "findOne", but still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a non-cursors in yur publish function.

You probably should have a error in `server` console saying

`publish function not-returning array of non-cursor` or something like that

try to publish a cursor

```
Meteor.publish("episode", function(episodeNumber) {
  check(episodeNumber, String);
  //check whether the episodes are existed or not
  console.log(Episodes.find({episodeNumber: episodeNumber}).count());
  return Episodes.find({episodeNumber: episodeNumber});
});
```

and also check your server console(terminal) for the errors

Comment: It returns 0 for the count.  See gist in comment above for actual output.